Angular 13 version preserveWhitespaces not working
I am using below angular version Angular version
I also use the preserveWhitespaces in tsconfig.json, but still my web page is looking like this:
screenshot
I added below property in tsconfig file but still it is not working.
Let me know what's wrong with it
